# How to read the value of a ReactNative.Style.t property with reason-react-native?

Tags: react-native, reason, reason-react-native

I would like to do the following:

```
 let marginTop =
   if (itemInfo##index == 0) {
     Style.viewStyle(~marginTop=style##paddingTop, ());
   } else {
     Style.viewStyle();
   }
```

But I get the following error:

```
This has type:
    ReactNative.Style.t (defined as ReactNative.Style.t)
  But somewhere wanted:
    Js.t('a)
```

Does anyone knows how I can read the value?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look too good of an idea to do it like so.

But in case you were wondering:

`StyleSheet.flatten(styles)##paddingTop`